"Sure is a nice feeling." - is it correct/common to say this way?
Dialog as subtitled in a movie (per my hearing the subtitling correctly):

Yeah, like old times.
I've missed this.
Sure is a nice feeling.

I suspect it is just conversational shortening of "sure, it is a nice feeling". Is is Ok/common to shorten like that?

It is expected here at ELL that one check a dictionary before posting such questions. Merriam-Webster explains that the adverb sure is a synonym of surely, one of whose definitions is “without doubt: certainly.” So there’s no shortening or conversational deletion going on.

Correction: There is conversational deletion, of the dummy subject it.

What @PaulTanenbaum said. Compare "Looks like rain" and "Sounds like you know what you're talking about" - both also with conversational deletion, of the dummy subject it.

@PaulTanenbaum. I've consulted three dictionaries, there were no "sure" as a noun. I do not understand who yours 1st comment explains. I see you corrected via 2nd comment, if 1st is not correct at all, why not delete 1st one?

Sure is never used as a noun. Did you suppose it was being used so here? The sentence you ask about doesn’t mean that being sure is pleasant, that it is pleasant to experience certainty.

What the sentence you ask about does mean mean is that it (something unspecified in the short excerpt you’ve included) is a very  pleasant sensation.

That unspecified something, that’s the referent of the deleted dummy pronoun it.

@PaulTanenbaum, I just wanted (and still want) to understand why you posted initially "the adverb sure is a synonym of surely", what was the logic?

Because as I understood your question, you didn’t understand how sure was being used. If you edit your question to clarify it and to include what efforts you made to resolve it yourself, then several of my comments can be deleted.

Sure is a nice feeling. =It's surely a nice feeling.

Sure, it's a nice feeling [so it is] sounds very Irish; [it] sure is a nice feeling sounds like very normal US English.


Sure is a nice feeling.

is typical spoken shortening of:

It sure is a nice feeling.

Yes, that's right. It is shortened that way.
Another one:

Fine with me. for It's fine with me.

There are too many instances to list them all. That said, the it is left out.

Nice to meet you. for It's nice to meet you.
Fine weather we're having. for It's nice weather we're having.

The dummy it is often left out in casual conversation. "Good to know, eh?" :)

The examples you gave (I guess common ones) are all omit in the beginning, whereas in mine example it was in the middle, hence I was not sure.

@Martian2020 I thought they were all different examples, which they could be. Even if they are not, all three hang together fine as dialogue. In all fairness, your question seems to be more about the last one than all three.
